# Trying to serialize in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following jsfiddle where I am trying to serialize a class:

HTML:

```
<content>
<div class="portlet portlet_1 portlet_content_1 new">some content here</div>
<div class="portlet portlet_1 portlet_content_1 new">some content here</div>
<div class="portlet portlet_1 portlet_content_1 new">some content here</div>
<div class="portlet portlet_2 portlet_content_2 new">some content here</div>
<div class="portlet portlet_2 portlet_content_2 new">some content here</div>
<div class="portlet portlet_3 portlet_content_3 new">some content here</div>
</content>

<button>Serialize</button>​
```

JS:

```
$("content").sortable();

$("button").on("click", function() {
    var data = $("content").sortable("serialize", {
        key: "item",
        attribute: "class"
    });
    alert(data);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WTTsB/2/

In the alert, I should get:

> item=1&item=1&item=1&item=2&item=2&item=3

I don't know how to deal with this because each div tag has multiple classes.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: In future please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should standalone from any other resource; consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future.

Comment: How exactly do you expect `sortable` to extract the number you want from the `class` attribute?

Comment: @Matt, Sorry, Will remember that for next time.

Comment: @lanzz, if each div had a single class, the above would work perfectly.  As each div has multiple classes, I don't know how to deal with that situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as phenomnomnominal said as the serializer method doesn't handle space, it cannot guess which class it has to parse so it parses the last it recognize. BUT you can force it with your own regex but I can't find any documentation on it, still it should be called like this :

```
var data = $("content").sortable("serialize", {
    key: "item",
    attribute: "class",
    expression: /(.+)_(.+)/
});
```

first group is your key attibute and the second group is your value; this parse class like this :

```
class="myclass_234"
```

to:

```
item=234
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/phenomnomnominal/WTTsB/5/

```
<content>
    <div class="new portlet portlet_1 portlet_content_1">some content here</div>
    <div class="new portlet portlet_1 portlet_content_1">some content here</div>
    <div class="new portlet portlet_1 portlet_content_1">some content here</div>
    <div class="new portlet portlet_2 portlet_content_2">some content here</div>
    <div class="new portlet portlet_2 portlet_content_2">some content here</div>
    <div class="new portlet portlet_3 portlet_content_3">some content here</div>
</content>
```

From [Sortable:](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#methods)

> It works by default by looking at the id of each item in the format 'setname_number', and > it spits out a hash like "setname[]=number&setname[]=number".

This must happen with some sort of string manipulation, so instead of getting "1", it was returning "1 new". Reordering the classes means your CSS etc. will stay the same, but that the function can read the attributes properly.

Comment: Why does changing the order of the classes fix this?  Looks like a hack, or making use of a bug?